# Passing a variable into a views block via hook_preprocess_views_view

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a block view for a commerce cart, and I'd like to add the cart quantity into the block. This is what I've tried so far:

```
// In template.php
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['name'] === 'commerce_cart') {
    $variables['quantity'] = 'x';
  }
}

// In block--views--commerce-cart.tpl.php
print $quantity;
```

The template file doesn't seem to know about the newly added variable, however, because I assume the theme function hasn't defined that unknown value as a possibility.

Is there a simple way to get this value into the template file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you need to transfer the variable from template.php to the views tpl.php? In theory you should be able to run any logic you're running in template.php in your views template...  also, as an alternative can you use PHP session vars?

Comment: Yes, the logic can be in a template file... but just even from that sentence you can recognise the antipattern! Hard logic shouldn't really be in a template file

Comment: If you look at this [DO tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/tools-and-best-practices/theme-coding-conventions) you're handling it the right way, so are you sure your block.tpl even fires? Can you test it with a dpm or test message?

Comment: Template file definitely fires. It's working fine as is with the commerce cart code in the tpl file, but I don't like it- I'd much rather the operative code be separated out from the tpl!